# Running Curl Command in Jenkins Behind Corporative Proxy

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, curl, sh

I'm having an issue when I try to execute a CURL command in one of the steps of a Jenkinsfile when it's working behind a proxy.

I'm working on Ubuntu 18 and I run the Jenkins container in like this:

```
docker run -d
-u root --privileged 
-v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home 
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
-v "$HOME":/home
-e JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins" 
--group-add 997
-p 8080:8080 
-p 50000:50000 
--name jenkins 
jenkinsci/blueocean
```

And then I have a simple `Jenkinsfile` that clones the code from a git repository, makes an image, pushes it to a registry and finally sends a Telegram message using curl.

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  environment {
    dockerImage = ''
  }

  stages {
     stage('Testing') {

      steps {
        echo 'testing'
      }
    }

   stage('Build image') {
      steps {
        script{
          dockerImage = docker.build("registry.***.com.ar/hellonode")
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Push image') {

      steps{
        script {
          docker.withRegistry('https://registry.***.com.ar', 'registryCredentials') {
            dockerImage.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
            dockerImage.push("latest")
          }
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Push Notification') {
        steps {
            script{
              
              withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'telegramToken', variable: 'TOKEN'),
              string(credentialsId: 'telegramChatId', variable: 'CHAT_ID')]) {
                
                sh '''
                curl -s -X \
                POST https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/sendMessage \
                -d chat_id=${CHAT_ID} \
                -d parse_mode="HTML" \
                -d text="  <b>Jenkins CI:</b> <b>Iniciando build $BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME</b> $JOB_NAME"
                '''
              }
            }
        }
    }

  }
}
```

And it fails when executing the curl command (I get an `ERROR: script returned exit code 7`).
But I think that it should be related to Linux or corporative Proxy, because I tested the same in my Windows machine without proxy and it worked.

Please let me know if I need to add further information, thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `-s` argument from curl & paste the output.

Comment: It says curl: `(7) Failed to connect to api.telegram.org port 443: Operation timed out`

Comment: looks like the traffic to `api.telegram.org` on port `443` is blocked. I don’t see `proxy` being used by your `curl`

Comment: If I'm within the container with `docker exec -it jenkins sh` and curl using the proxy  `curl -x XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:8080 -s -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot.../sendMessage" -d chat_id="..." -d parse_mode="HTML" -d text="<b>Jenkins CI:</b> <b>Iniciando</b>"` it works, but it doesn't if I put this in `Jenkinsfile`

Comment: Your container & Jenkins are on the same network?

Comment: Thank you for your help, as you suggested I could resolve it by working with the proxy in the curl command which at first maybe because of arguments order didn't seem to work. Thanks @harshavmb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Jenkins is behind the corporate proxy, you have to pass proxy information to curl to connect to target services.

[curl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) man page says, you can pass proxy information with either `--proxy` or `-x`(shortcut) argument.

```
sh '''
                curl -s --proxy <protocol>://<proxy-host>:<proxy-port> -X \
                POST https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/sendMessage \
                -d chat_id=${CHAT_ID} \
                -d parse_mode="HTML" \
                -d text="  <b>Jenkins CI:</b> <b>Iniciando build $BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME</b> $JOB_NAME"
                '''
```

This can also set via env vars `http_proxy`/`https_proxy`.

In case if proxy expects basic auth, it can be passed like `<protocol>://<proxy-username>:<proxy-password@><proxy-host>:<proxy-port>`

Finally, while debugging `curl`, it's important to remove `-s` argument as it silently mutes the output.